# Django static files do not load in correctly

Tags: python, django

I have done everything as always (I think), but for some reason django `static` files not working perfectly. I tried to find a solution but nothing helped.

This is the site now:
[image: This is the site now]

How it should be:

[image: How it should look like]

Inside `static` folder I have `css`, `images`, and so on. I have `{% load static %}` on the top of the html. I do not have any errors in the console.

One line of the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

My settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

My folders:

[image: Files]

> SOLUTION:    I have deleted pycache folders and the migrate folder,
>   then started the server again. It solved the problem. I do not know
>   the real reason, why...

Comment: Is it `DEBUG=False`?

Comment: I tried it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted pycache folders and migrate folder. Now everything semms to be fine :) I do not know what was the reason of the problem.